# How to interpolate between two points for higher resolution drawing

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, math, graphics, drawing

In flash, I use `lineTo` to draw a line between two points. This is working well, but I'm finding that on slower computers, the line is jagged because not as many mouse events are firing.

I want to 'smooth' the line out, to add more points in between each point that the mouse registers:

[image: Illustration]

The black lines show the result, the green ones are what I want. The red dots are actual points, and the green ones are interpolated.

I have tried to code this myself but I can't seem to get it right, here is the code anyway:

```
var interX:Number = lastMouseX+(lastMouseSpeed.x/2);
var interY:Number = lastMouseY+(lastMouseSpeed.y/2);

//Also tried: lastMouseX+(this.mouseX-lastMouseX)/2;
// also jittery

graphics.lineTo(interX, interY);

graphics.lineTo(this.mouseX, this.mouseY);

lastMouseSpeed.x = this.mouseX-lastMouseX;
lastMouseSpeed.y = this.mouseY-lastMouseY;

lastMouseX = this.mouseX;
lastMouseY = this.mouseY;
```

the result is much more jagged than the normal one.

Sorry, but I can't give screenshots (for some reason it copies my screen as black)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want something like [spline interpolation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpolation#Spline_interpolation), though other approaches are possible.

The reason your current approach isn't working is that what you want to do for the point between red points 1 and 2 depends on red point 3, but you're equations don't account for this.  Accounting for it makes it possible to appropriately consider the curvature, but it's more complicated though.